# git stash list or git show , returning ( most +s +'/---': 1: most: not found ) What is this?

Tags: git, git-stash

Not sure if I need to upgrade git or I have something configured or broken?

I can push, pull, tag everything else just cannot seem to list stashes and stuff. I can't seem to locate this Error if it is one ( **git stash list** or **git show** return console output: " **most +s +'/---': 1: most: not found** " ) when googling it.

I can actually stash and pop items. Using git version: 1.7.5.4

Answer (score 2):

You have git configured to use `most` as your pager, but that command isn't installed.  Either install it or choose a different pager.  The pager setting could be coming from either the `core.pager` setting in one of the git config files or the `$GIT_PAGER` environment variable.

Comment: Appreciate it. Yeah, I just removed it form gitconfig for now. One of our other developers had it in their not sure why. Not sure what pager = most +s +'/---' does for us.